# Are there any downsides to using "multiDexEnabled"?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

### Background

According to this post ([What does "multiDexEnabled true" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856068/what-does-multidexenabled-true-mean)). By enabling the configuration setting `multiDexEnabled`, you are telling android it is OK to generate more than 1 DEX file for the APK.

My question is why does android, by default, only generate 1 DEX file then? Is there some computational overhead for using multiple DEX files? Is there some other limitations too? (e.g. limiting the abilities of proguard?)

### Question

Is there any downside to using `multiDexEnabled`?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503348/disadvantages-in-multidexing-the-android-application

Comment: @VivekMaskara Thank you